# Как создать куки и сохранить в БД?

Tags: php, cookie

Пытаюсь создать куки, для сбора информации о пользователе .

1. Вначале проверяла новый пользователь или нет
2. Если новый, то добавляла бы данные он пользователе в БД (мак-адрес,браузер,ссылку перехода...)
3. Если меченый, то просто обновляла бы информацию о нем.

накидал приблизительно такой код, но не работает...подскажите решение , 
пожалуйста.

```
// Параметры соединения с сервером MySQL
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root"; 
$pswd = "";
$maxNumVisitors=10;

// Имя базы данных
$database = "myTracker";

// Имя таблицы 
$visitors_table = "visitors";
@mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL server!");

// Выбрать базу данных
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Couldn't select $database database!");

// Максимальное количество посещений, отображаемое в таблице $maxNumVisitors = "5";
// Имя cookie
$cookieName = "visitorlog";



 function definition_mac() {

        if(PHP_OS == 'Linux'){  $macAddr = exec("grep ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." /proc/net/arp | awk '{print $4}'");  }
        elseif(PHP_OS == 'WINNT'){

            $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $macAddr=false;
            $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
            $lines=explode("\n", $arp);

            foreach($lines as $line){
                $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
                if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress){ $macAddr=$cols[1]; }
            }
        };
        return $macAddr;


function browser_info ($agent) {

// Определить тип браузера
// Искать сигнатуру Internet Explorer
if (ereg('MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})', $agent, $version)):
$browse_type = "IE";
$browse_version = $version[1];

// Искать сигнатуру Opera
elseif (ereg( 'Opera ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})', $agent, $version)):
$browse_type = "Opera";
$browse_version = $version[1];

// Искать сигнатуру Netscape. Проверка браузера Netscape
// *должна* выполняться после проверки Internet Explorer и Opera,
// поскольку все эти браузеры любят сообщать имя
// Mozilla вместе с настоящим именем.
elseif (ereg( 'Mozilla/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})', $agent, $version)) :
$browse_type = "Netscape";
$browse_version = $version[1];

// Если это не Internet Explorer, Opera или Netscape.
// значит, мы обнаружили неизвестный браузер,
else :
$browse_type = "Unknown";
$browse_version = "Unknown";
endif;

// Вернуть тип и версию браузера в виде массива
return array ($browse_type, $browse_version);
```

Comment: что именно "не работает"-то? опишите ожидаемое и наблюдаемое поведение кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой пример функции, которая проверяет установлена ли кука "user", если нет, то устанавливает ее на 7 дней:

```
function isUser()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        setcookie('user', '1', time() + 3600*24*7); //поставим куку на 7 дней
        return false;
    }
}

if (isUser()) {
    //пользователей уже посещал сайт, обновляем информацию
    //...
} else {
    //пользователь раньше не заходил, заводим нового
    //...
}
```

Смотрите вводную страничку о [cookies](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php) и в частности функцию [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php).

```
$name;     //название
$value;    //значение
$delay;    //срок жизни в секундах
$newValue; //новое значение

//установить
setcookie($name, $value, time() + $delay);

//прочитать
echo $_COOKIE[$name];

//обновить
setcookie($name, $newValue);

//удалить
unset($_COOKIE[$name]); //первый вариант
setcookie($name, $value, time() - 1); //второй вариант
```